# Searching in a list inside a dict in Python - Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, find, pymongo

Hope everybody is doing just fine.

I've stored data with Mongodb with the following structure:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5f788e29d55317c9cedf2'), 'num': '5512', 'person': [['John', 'Leader'], ['Mary', 'Follower']], 'valid': True}
```

I'm trying to search for string within the key "person", but with no success so far.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
name = "John"
rgx = re.compile('.*(%s).*'%name, re.IGNORECASE)
selection = db.collection.find({"person": rgx})
```

But it returns empty everytime.

Any ideas on why and what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you change your data model, otherwise your queries are going to be a world of pain. But if you can't, this query would work using the [`$elemMatch` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/):

```
print(list(db.mycollection.find({'person': {'$elemMatch': {'$elemMatch': {'$in': ['John']}}}})))
```